# Rounding Numbers with bc in Bash

Tags: linux, bash, bc

I want to compute an average with 3 decimal figures, rounded to nearest, using `bc`.

For example:

> average of 3, 3 and 5 should yield 3.667

and

> average of 3, 3 and 4 should yield 3.333

I tried:

```
echo "scale=3; $sum/$n+0.0005" | bc
```

but `scale` doesn't behave as I expect. What can I do to solve my problem?

Comment: You're adding `0.0005`, so `bc` gladly answers with 4 digits after decimal point.

Comment: So what should i do ?

Comment: How about you remove `+0.0005`?

Comment: Why do you need that?

Comment: because if number is 9.9999

Comment: i should prinf 10.000

Comment: bc dont round that number

Comment: So you're having an [XYproblem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: and i want to how can i do that,  not just for a problem

Comment: I hope you read the link I put in my previous comment. You should definitely edit your question and specify: 1. Clearly state what you want to achieve: _I want to compute an average with 3 decimal figures, rounded to nearest_. 2. State what you tried, and say why it doesn't work.

Comment: sorry im not good at english and i cant express my porblem clearly

Comment: There are a load of answers to your question here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/179898/how-to-round-decimals-using-bc-in-bash

Comment: thanks so much this will help a lot

Comment: I completely rephrased you question, with some examples. Please check that the examples really correspond to what you want to achieve! And also, from this, learn how to ask a question!

Comment: i will try to ask questions like this thanks again

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your trick to add `0.0005` is not a bad idea. Though, it doesn't quite work that way. `scale` is used internally when `bc` performs some operations (like divisions).

In your case, it would be better to perform the division first, maybe using a large `scale` or the `-l` switch to `bc`<sup>1</sup> (if your version supports it), then add `0.0005` and then set `scale=3` and perform an operation involving `scale` internally to have the truncation performed.

Something like:

```
`a=$sum/$n+0.0005; scale=3; a/1`
```

Of course, you'll want to proceed differently whether `sum` is positive or negative. Fortunately, `bc` has some conditional operators.

```
`a=$sum/$n; if(a>0) a+=0.0005 else if (a<0) a-=0.0005; scale=3; a/1`
```

You'll then want to format this answer using `printf`.

Wrapped in a function `round` (where you can optionally select the number of decimal figures):

```
round() {
    # $1 is expression to round (should be a valid bc expression)
    # $2 is number of decimal figures (optional). Defaults to three if none given
    local df=${2:-3}
    printf '%.*f\n' "$df" "$(bc -l <<< "a=$1; if(a>0) a+=5/10^($df+1) else if (a<0) a-=5/10^($df+1); scale=$df; a/1")"
}
```

Try it:

```
gniourf$ round "(3+3+4)/3"
3.333
gniourf$ round "(3+3+5)/3"
3.667
gniourf$ round "-(3+3+5)/3"
-3.667
gniourf$ round 0
0.000
gniourf$ round 1/3 10
0.3333333333
gniourf$ round 0.0005
0.001
gniourf$ round 0.00049
0.000
```

---

<sup>1</sup> with the `-l` switch, `scale` is set to `20`, which should be plenty enough.

Comment: Thank you! it works. But it seems i have to work a lot to write codes like this

Comment: I worked on C++ and it was easy because syntax wasnt important

Comment: As i understand syntax (space .. etc) very important in Bash

Comment: Yeah, Bash's syntax is completely crazy. Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

Next function round argument 'x' to 'd' digits:

```
define r(x, d) {
    auto r, s

    if(0 > x) {
        return -r(-x, d)
    }
    r = x + 0.5*10^-d
    s = scale
    scale = d
    r = r*10/10
    scale = s  
    return r
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution is not that flexibile (it just converts float to int), but it can deal with negative numbers:

```
e=$( echo "scale=0; (${e}+0.5)/1" | bc -l )
if [[ "${e}" -lt 0 ]] ; then
    e=$(( e - 1 ))
fi
```